# Download a CSV with AJAX

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, jquery, csv

I am using C# and JavaScript.  my goal is to send an ajax request that results in a CSV file being downloaded.  The CSV will be generated on the server side in an ashx page.  Currently the application is able to download a CSV but by using a form instead of an AJAX request, however the backend code is the same.

Here is the ajax request I have which fails:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "myDir/x.ashx/exportAllData",
    type: 'POST',
    data: { 
        id:8
    },
    success: function(ajaxResult){
    console.log(ajaxResult);
    }
});
```

Here is the Form method that does work:

```
var $form = $(document.createElement('form'))
    .attr({
        action: 'myDir/x.ashx/exportAllData',
            method: 'POST'
        })
        .css('display', 'none')
        .appendTo('body');         
    $form.submit();
    $form.empty().remove();
```

Here is the code in the handler(C#), which is the same for both the above cases:

```
else if(action == "exportalldata")
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.AppendLine("test1,test2,test3,test4,test5");
       context.Response.Clear();
       context.Response.ContentType = "application/csv";
       context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition",       "attachment;filename=data.csv");                
     context.Response.Write(sb.ToString());
     context.Response.End();
}
```

Comment: Properly duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545311/download-a-file-by-jquery-ajax

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is you can't.  Browsers cannot download files via ajax.  It has to be done via form post.

Comment: or GET... actually it doesn't have anything to do with the Request itself, but with the "thing" handling the response. Javascript isn't able to store data in filesystem.

Comment: A fair clarification.  JavaScript can't interact with the disk for security reasons, since it's a vulnerability.

Answer (score 0):

You could modify your server-side code to output to a static file within your webroot and return a URL pointing to it. You could then set `window.location.href` to the URL.

Comment: that would be an idea. The file doesn't even need to be in the root as long as you've got a handler to get it from where it is.

Answer (score 0):

If you populate date yourself you can use [this](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_plugin_for_requesting_ajax_like_file_downloads/)

jQuery Plugin for Requesting Ajax-like File Downloads

example from link:

```
$.download('/export.php','filename=mySpreadsheet&format=xls&content=' + spreadsheetData );
```